# create a image gallery that cache and download images from the web with odd swipe action

Tags: android, image, swipe, download

I'm new to android development and I want to create a navigation concept which is a little weird for android and not sure what is the best way to develop this.

In a nutshell the application hold an endless collection of images downloaded from the server  as the collection processed with buffering to make it smoother.
The general Idea is that I see the image full screen and have the ability to either swipe left or right, each direction represent a different action on the image and will show a small image near the image during the swipe to indicate which action I selected. Afterwards regardless on which action I selected it will swipe to the next image in the collection.
What would be the best direction to solve this problem, PagerAdapte or FragmentStatePagerAdapter (since I don’t have the ability to navigate back to an image)? Manually implementing the swipe using listeners?
Also how do I deal with showing the small images without making the code too awkward?
Should I use Volley for the image downloading?
[image]

Comment: Are you stuck with the "cache" part?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is [**Bitmapfun**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/5f51b7f/samples/training/bitmapfun). Try implement it. First screen of this application is `gridview`. If you click one of those items those images are shown in [**ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) you have to implement the `ViewPager` section. It also cached those images as you mentioned in your question.

- [Github link](https://github.com/wuyexiong/bitmapfun)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem:

First use volley to download images because:

1-  Volley is open source and you can easily configure it, the concept behind it is very simple.
(for example you can change cache size, thread pool size for network requests and so on)

2-  Volley uses two level caches, so makes you feel free about memory and …

3-  Volley decodes images for you on the worker thread and that’s another problem you may face it but Volley solves it for you.

4-  Volley handle configuration changes so on the flight requests dose not duplicate if orientation changes and you request them again(for the first section)

5-  You can ask volley to deliver you an image in a different sizes so your thumbnail image and real image all can be delivered with just changing the request image size

6-  You can change the HttpStack of it to run on a OKHttp , which is more optimized for all version down to I think 2.2

All you need to do is just spend some time to understand it and configure it to get most performance from it and use it’s two level caches to show your slides.

For showing the images I do not recommend you any of FragmentPagerAdapter nor FragmentStatePagerAdapter because:

FragmentPagerAdapter is not suitable for large collection of fragments because it store all fragments in memory and you will soon get OOM exception.

FragmentStatePagerAdapter is good because it handles configuration changes but it also stores at minimum 3 pages in memory which one of them is the last page you just visited so because you do not want to go back to last image it wastes memory for you.

I think best solution is manually implementing the swipe using listeners with the idea of off screen loading, to load for example two next images in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). It is open source and has some pretty awesome features.

Answer (score 0):

you can refere this " https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery " link hope it`ll helps u :)